# Avro schema invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

The avro schema described [here](https://gist.github.com/trickster/8dffd6b14d217a462d986bcba7398ecf) is valid. But when creating Pub/Sub schema with it gives an error.

```bash
gcloud pubsub schemas create schema1 --type=AVRO --definition="$(cat schema.json)"

ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.schemas.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Checked with this python script

```py
import avro.io
with open('schema.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
parsed_schema = avro.schema.parse(data)

print(parsed_schema.canonical_form)
```

Answer (score 1):

The scheme exceeds the maximum size limit as specified in the [Pub/Sub quotas](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits) of 50KB. We are considering increasing this limit, though.